# Scala playframework implicit reader writer for Timestamp

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.1, playframework-json

I'm using  play.api.libs.json._ library. I have this kind of Scala class.  I need to read / write this class in Json format. As there is no implicit reader/ writer for Timestamp. I have to provide my own. I tried couple ways unfortunately none of them worked. Could you please suggest me how it is done? Thanks in advance!

```
case class Event(id: Long, startTime: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = None, endTime: Option[java.sql.Timestamp] = None)
```

I would like to POST / GET in following Json format

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "startTime": "2011-10-02 18:48:05.123456",
  "endTime": "2011-10-02 20:48:05.123456"
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just add before Json Reader or Json Format for Event class

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json._
import play.api.libs.json._ 

def timestampToDateTime(t: Timestamp): DateTime = new DateTime(t.getTime)

def dateTimeToTimestamp(dt: DateTime): Timestamp = new Timestamp(dt.getMillis)

implicit val timestampFormat = new Format[Timestamp] {

    def writes(t: Timestamp): JsValue = toJson(timestampToDateTime(t))

    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Timestamp] = fromJson[DateTime](json).map(dateTimeToTimestamp)

  }
```

Comment: toJson, timestampToDateTime, fromJson, dateTimeToTimestamp undefined compiler error. Do I need to import some  additional library?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add implementation for this functions

Comment: dateTimeToTimestamp takes DateTime parameter. So how to call  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Timestamp] = fromJson[DateTime](json).map(dateTimeToTimestamp)?  Still toJson, fromJson undefined.

Comment: dont forget to add import play.api.libs.json.Json._ or add Json. before toJson, fromJson

Comment: to parse Timestamp you can just use Json.fromJson[Timestamp](json). timestampFormat will be used implicitly

Comment: It seems ur answer is  converting between DateTime and  Timestamp. But my question was how to convert json which comes as String. So how to convert json/String to Timestamp. I dont need   DateTime. Coz play provides  DateTime implicit reader and writer. Please update ur answer if u know how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I also needed to import `play.api.libs.json.JodaReads._` and `play.api.libs.json.JodaWrites._`

Comment: which DateTime class does this use?

Answer (score 5):

What I did code for a personal project:

```
implicit object timestampFormat extends Format[Timestamp] {
  val format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'")
  def reads(json: JsValue) = {
    val str = json.as[String]
    JsSuccess(new Timestamp(format.parse(str).getTime))
  }
  def writes(ts: Timestamp) = JsString(format.format(ts))
}
```

And don't forget to import this:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.json._
```

It respects Javascript dates standard.

Source: https://github.com/BinaryBrain/Gamers/blob/master/server/play/app/models/Package.scala